# Nest a string inside an array n times

Tags: code-golf, string

You must produce a function which nests a string `s` inside an array, `n` times

```
>>> N("stackoverflow",2)
[['stackoverflow']]
```

## Parameters:

1. `s` - An ascii string
2. `n` - An integer `>= 0`

### Rules

- Shortest code wins.
- The output will be a nested `array`, `list` or `tuple` (or similar type based off an array)

### Test Cases

```
>>> N("stackoverflow",0)
'stackoverflow'
>>> N("stackoverflow",1)
['stackoverflow']
>>> N("stackoverflow",5)
[[[[['stackoverflow']]]]]
```

---

<sub>Inspired by: [Nesting a string inside a list n times ie list of a list of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083007/nesting-a-string-inside-a-list-n-times-ie-list-of-a-list-of-a-list#40083670)</sub>

Comment: Does the output have to be a list, or can it be a string representing that list?

Comment: Can we take the parameters in any order?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix I think unless explicitly forbidden, yes - you can take the input in any reasonable format (which would include taking the two as a list too I believe). Maybe someone more experienced can point to a relevant meta post.

Comment: Will the string ever include an escaped `"`? E.g. `N("stack\"overflow",5)`

Comment: @Riley It could contain any ascii character

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix Should be in the order in the question

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Should be a list

Comment: Lists don't exist in in some languages. In one of those can I output a string  instead?

Comment: @Riley What about an array, if not then a string

Comment: I have a solution in sed where a string is the only option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
W¡
```

Slightly confusing, since: (1) Jelly has no strings, only lists of characters; and (2); the output wont show the nesting. To see that this actually is doing what is asked look at a Python string representation of the result with:

```
W¡ŒṘ
```

An extra pair of `[]` will be present since the string itself will be a list of characters. [For example](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=V8KhxZLhuZg&input=&args=InN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3ci+NQ)

#### How?

```
W¡ - Main link: s, n
W  - wrap left, initially s, in a list
 ¡ - repeat previous link n times
```

The proof-of-concept code adds:

```
W¡ŒṘ - Main link: s, n
  ŒṘ - Python string representation
```

Comment: [Better output representation](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/80ML/2vqH249Oerhzxv//SsUlicnZ@WWpRWk5@eVK/00B)

Comment: "Better" in that it *looks* like strings are being used... it does not show that a list of characters is actually being used though.

Answer (score 17):

## Java and C#, 62 bytes

```
Object f(String s,int n){return n<1?s:new Object[]{f(s,n-1)};}
```

Should work without modification in both Java and C#.

Comment: Smart! +1 I was trying to get it to work in Java by nesting a String-array, which didn't really work out. Using an Object as return type and nest it in an Object[] is just the solution required for this challenge, since Object[] (or any array) is also an Object themselves. Nice one.

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

**Code**

```
`F)
```

**Explanation**

```
`   # Flatten the input array on the stack.
 F  # Element_2 times do:
  ) # Wrap the total stack into a single array.
```

This means that this also works for the **0**-testcase, since the string is already on the stack.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=YEYp&input=WyJzdGFja292ZXJmbG93IiwgNV0)

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), 20 bytes

```
d=>g=n=>n--?[g(n)]:d
```

Although people normally nag me to curry my functions for the 1-byte saving, this is a case where it actually contributes to the solution.

Comment: Great use of currying. I think you can make it slightly more readable: `d=>g=n=>n?[g(n-1)]:d`

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
List~Nest~##&
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](//sourceforge.net/projects/cjam), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
{{a}*}
```

[Online interpreter](//cjam.aditsu.net#code=r%7E%7E%7Ba%7D*&input=%5B%22stackoverflow%225%5D)

This is an unnamed function that takes its arguments from the stack as `S N`, `S` being the string and `N` being the wraps. You can execute it with the `~` operator, meaning eval.

Explanation:

```
{{a}*}
{      Open block    [A B]
 {     Open block    [A]
  a    Wrap in array [[A]]
   }   Close block   [A B λwrap]
    *  Repeat        [A:wrap(*B)]
     } Close block   ["S" N λ(λwrap)repeat]
```

Comment: Just use an unnamed block to avoid the awkward input format `{{a}*}` or `{'a*~}`.

Comment: @MartinEnder I'm afraid it would take bytes, though, and I think that input format is 100% acceptable. It's just a list, and I think there is no restriction as to how those two parameters are entered. Also, I never named the block.

Comment: I don't know what you mean about the bytes? Both of those solutions are only 6 bytes.

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh, were these whole solutions? I thought you were talking about extending my program, but you just converted it to a function? Well, that changes the whole point. I'm a newbie at CJam/GolfScript/Pyth. I prefer the first one because it's more comprehensible (repeat `{a}` n times) instead of the second one (produce a string of n `a`s and execute it).

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript ES6, 23 bytes

Recursive function

```js
f=(a,i)=>i?f([a],--i):a

console.log(f("stackoverflow",0))
console.log(f("stackoverflow",1))
console.log(f("stackoverflow",2))
console.log(f("stackoverflow",5))
```

Currying results in the same length

```
f=a=>i=>i?f([a])(--i):a
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
tT,?h:T:gi
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=dFQsP2g6VDpnaQ&input=WyJzdGFjayBvdmVyZmxvdyI6NV0&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
tT,            T is the integer (second element of the Input)
   ?h:T:g      The list [String, T, built-in_group]
         i     Iterate: Apply built-in_group T times to String
```

This would be 3 bytes if it wasn't bugged. Here we need all this to get the list `[String, T, built-in_group]` even though `[String, T]` is already our input.

Unfortunately `:g` directly results in `[[String, T], built-in_group]`, which is not recognized properly by `i` because the integer `T` is inside the first list.

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, 6 bytes

```
ji:"Xh
```

This produces a nested cell array as the output. With MATL's default display, however, you can't necessary *see* that's what it is since it won't show all of the curly braces. The demo below is a slightly modified version which shows the string representation of the output.

```
ji:"Xh]&D
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=amk6IlhoXSZE&input=c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdwo1)

**Explanation**

```
j       % Explicitly grab the first input as a string
i       % Explicitly grab the second input as an integer (n)
:"      % Create an array [1...n] and loop through it
    Xh  % Each time through the loop place the entire stack into a cell array
        % Implicit end of for loop and display
```

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, 3 bytes

```
V]1
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=V%5D1&input=4%0Astackoverflow)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 32 bytes

```
N=lambda s,n:n and[N(s,n-1)]or s
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 60 Bytes

```
for($r=$argv[1];$i++<$argv[2];)$r=[$r];echo json_encode($r);
```

48 Bytes if it looks only like the task

```
for($r=$argv[1];$i++<$argv[2];)$r="[$r]";echo$r;
```

Comment: I think a direct rewrite of the question owner's own Python answer is still the shortest in PHP too: `function f($s,$n){return$n?[f($s,$n-1)]:$s;}`.

Comment: `print_r()` and, if you don't like that option, `serialize()` are both shorter than `json_encode()`ing it while differentiating the output.

Comment: BTW, that lonely `')` at the end of code looks strange.

Comment: @manatwork Copy and Paste error Thank You

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](//github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
]Fw
```

[Permalink](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=%60%5DFw&input=4%0A3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0Astackoverflow%0A1%0Astackoverflow%0A5%0Astackoverflow&input_size=2)

This will output something like `...[[[[['string']]]]]...`. It will not quote for zero depth: `string`.

Explanation:

```
]Fw
   Q Implicit: Eval first input line
]    Function: Wrap in array
  w  Input line
 F   Apply multiple times
```

If you want quoting on zero depth, use this 4-byte solution instead (explanation):

```
`]Fw
    Q Implicit: Eval first input line
 ]    Function: Wrap in array
   w  Input line
  F   Apply multiple times
`     Representation
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby: 23 bytes

```
->n,s{n.times{s=[s]};s}
```

This is updated to make it a callable Proc rather than the original snippet. I'd be interested to know whether there's a way to have `s` implicitly returned rather than having to explicitly return it.

Comment: Generally your "a few more words" should be an explanation of how your code works. But it's a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: “You must produce a function” This is a code snippet. Unless explicitly specified otherwise, input and output has to be handled explicitly by the code or implicitly by the interpreter if it has such feature. You can not expect some global variables to be set and you can not just leave the result in some global variables.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! [All answers should be callable functions or full programs, though.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) In your case, the shortest fix would be to use an unnamed function like `->s,n{...}`.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, and Martin, thank you for your encouragement and helpful input, I have learned something and will update. manatwork, I've got thick skin and have plenty of points on SO but you know that blunt statements like that scare newbies away from Stack sites and intimidate them. Seems a shame no?

Answer (score 3):

### C, <s>44 bytes</s>, 41 bytes

```
int*n(int*s,int a){return a?n(&s,a-1):s;}
```

You can test it by doing the following:

```
int main(void) {
    char* s = "stackoverflow";

    /* Test Case 0 */
    int* a = n(s,0);
    printf("'%s'\n", a);

    /* Test Case 1 */
    int* b = n(s,1);
    printf("['%s']\n", *b);

    /* Test Case 2 */
    int** c = n(s,2);
    printf("[['%s']]\n", **c);

    /* Test Case 3 */
    int*** d = n(s,3);
    printf("[[['%s']]]\n", ***d);

    /* Test Case 4 */
    int********** e = n(s,10);
    printf("[[[[[[[[[['%s']]]]]]]]]]\n", **********e);

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
'stackoverflow'
['stackoverflow']
[['stackoverflow']]
[[['stackoverflow']]]
[[[[[[[[[['stackoverflow']]]]]]]]]]
```

Of course, you'll get warnings. This works on `gcc` on bash on my Windows machine (`gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)`, as well as on a true Linux machine (`gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)`).

Comment: Not sure about other compilers, but `int*n(s,a)int*s;{return!a?s:n(&s,a-1);}` works with gcc.

Comment: It segfaults for `cc -v` -> `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)`.

Comment: I have changed `n(s,3);` to `n(s,6);` and then to `n(s,0);` and found your solution incorrect. Check and fix it

Comment: It seems that your `n` function does not output `[` and `]`, and solution require some update

Comment: Can you drop the `!` from the ternary condition and switch the order of `s` and `n(&s,a-1)` to save a byte?

Comment: @VolAnd When you call `n(s,6)`, you have to change `***` to `******` in the variable declaration and use. This is needed exactly because the function does what it is expected to do: nest the string into an array several (here: 6) times. Of course you would still get three levels of `[]` because they are hardcoded. I think the program shouldn't output them at all. This challenge is not about brackets, it is about nesting. Some languages print arrays with brackets, C hasn't any builtin function to print them at all. So what? It is not needed here.

Comment: Can you drop the spaces after the `*` in the function signature?

Comment: @VolAnd I added more test cases - you can't change `n(s,3)` to `n(s,6)` without changing the variable type. Since `n(s,6)` would create an "array" (really just 6 nested pointers), you need to assign it to a type of `int******`, and then dereference that value 6 times to get the true value.

Comment: @VolAnd The function doesn't need to output anything - it just has to return a nested array (or in this case, a nested pointer).

Comment: @Riley Thanks! Just updated the count :)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Thanks! Just updated the count :)

Answer (score 3):

## k, 3 bytes

```
,:/
```

Taken as a dyadic function, `/` will iteratively apply the left-hand function `,:` (`enlist`) n times to the second argument.

Example:

```
k),:/[3;"hello"]
,,,"hello"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 5 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.12 bytes

```
s{KZO
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLi6u9o_whbKjQgvXFJYnJ2fllqUVpOfnlXKYQYQA)

If the inputs could be taken in any order, the leading `s` could be dropped.

##### Explanation

```
s{KZO  # Implicit input
s      # Swap so the number is on top
 {K    # Loop input number of times:
   ZO  # Wrap in a list
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 25 characters

Rewrite of [jamylak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4094/jamylak)'s [Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96488).

```ruby
f=->s,n{n>0?[f[s,n-1]]:s}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> f=->s,n{n>0?[f[s,n-1]]:s}
=> #<Proc:0x00000002006e80@(irb):1 (lambda)>

irb(main):002:0> f["stackoverflow",0]
=> "stackoverflow"

irb(main):003:0> f["stackoverflow",1]
=> ["stackoverflow"]

irb(main):004:0> f["stackoverflow",5]
=> [[[[["stackoverflow"]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

### C# 6, 50 bytes

```
dynamic a(dynamic s,int n)=>n<2?s:a(new[]{s},n-1);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n<1`? Also -2 bytes if you use `object` instead of `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 24 bytes

```
f=->*s,n{s[n]||f[s,n-1]}
```

Called the same as in [manatwork's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96491/6828), but a weirder implementation. `*s` wraps the input (a possibly-nested string) in an array. Then if `n` is zero, `s[n]` returns the first element of `s`, turning the function into a no-op. Otherwise, it returns `nil` since `s` will only ever have one element, so we pass through to the recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 6 bytes

```
Àñys$]
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w4DDsXlzJF0&input=J0hlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEi&args=NA)

Explanation:

```
À      "Arg1 times
 ñ     "repeat:
  ys$  "surround this line
     ] "with square brackets
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 23 bytes

```perl6
{($^a,{[$_]}...*)[$^b]}
```

### Expanded:

```perl6
{ # bare block lambda with two placeholder parameters ｢$a｣ and ｢$b｣
  (

    # generate Sequence

    $^a,       # declare first input
    { [ $_ ] } # lambda that adds one array layer
    ...        # do that until
    *          # Whatever

  )[ $^b ]     # index into the sequence
}
```

Comment: Perl never ceases to amaze me with its syntax

Answer (score 2):

### Agda, 173 bytes

Since the return type of the function depends on the number given as argument, this is clearly a case where a dependently typed language should be used. Unfortunately, golfing isn't easy in a language where you have to import naturals and lists to use them. On the plus side, they use `suc` where I would have expected the verbose `succ`. So here is my code:

```
module l where
open import Data.List
open import Data.Nat
L : ℕ -> Set -> Set
L 0 a = a
L(suc n)a = List(L n a)
f : ∀ n{a}-> a -> L n a
f 0 x = x
f(suc n)x = [ f n x ]
```

(I hope I found all places where spaces can be omitted.) `L` is a type function that given a natural `n` and a type `a` returns the type of `n` times nested lists of `a`, so `L 3 Bool` would be the type of lists of lists of lists of `Bool` (if we had imported `Bool`). This allows us to express the type of our function  as `(n : ℕ) -> {a : Set} -> a -> L n a`, where the curly braces make that argument implicit. The code uses a shorter way to write this type. The function can now be defined in an obvious way by pattern matching on the first argument.

Loading this file with an `.agda` extension into emacs allows to use `C-c C-n` (evaluate term to normal form), input for example `f 2 3` and get the correct answer in an awkward form: `(3 ∷ []) ∷ []`. Now of course if you want to do that with strings you have to import them...

Comment: Just remembered that I could write `→` instead of `->`, but of course that increases the size of an UTF-8 encoded file.

Comment: My ugly translation of this into Haskell is somewhat shorter. I have to stick to manual unary to keep it short.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@[X]}gNÅ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QFtYXX1nTsU&input=OAoiSmFwdCIKLVE)

Answer (score 1):

### R, <strike>39</strike> 40 bytes

EDIT: Fixed the `n=0` issue thanks to @rturnbull.

Function that takes two inputs `s` (string) and `n` (nestedness) and outputs the nested list. Note that R-class `list` natively prints output differently than most other languages, however, is functionally similar to a key/value map (with possibly unnamed keys) or a list in python.

```
f=function(s,n)if(n)list(f(s,n-1))else s
```

**Example**

```
> f=function(s,n)if(n)list(f(s,n-1))else s
> f("hello",3)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "hello"


> # to access the string nested 5 times in the "list-object" named "list" we can do the following
> list = f("nested string",5)
> list[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "nested string"
```

Comment: Very nice! It doesn't give the desired output for `n=0`, though. Before I saw your answer, I came up with a recursive solution which can deal with `n=0`, but it's 1 byte longer than your solution (40 bytes): `f=function(s,n)if(n)list(f(s,n-1))else s`

Comment: @rturnbull You're of course right. Your solution is much more elegant in my opinion and I totally forgot about the `n=0` case. However, your solution is actually `38` bytes excluding the naming of the function and hence shorter. Great catch

Comment: Since it's a recursive function it must be named, unfortunately! (Otherwise it can't interpret the `f(s,n-1)` call inside of it.) Recursive anonymous functions are not possible in R, as far as I know.

Comment: @rturnbull You're again right. Updating the answer.

Comment: A year later, I've golfed off another byte: `f=function(s,n)'if'(n,list(f(s,n-1)),s)`.

Answer (score 1):

### [Jellyfish](http://github.com/iatorm/jellyfish), 8 bytes

```
p\Ai
 ;i
```

[Try it online!](http://jellyfish.tryitonline.net/#code=cFxBaQogO2k&input=NAoidGVzdCI)

Unary `;` wraps its argument in a list. Binary `\` on a function and a value `n` iterates that function `n` times.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```
function n($s,$n){return$n?n([$s],--$n):$s;}
```

nothing sophisticated, just a recursive function

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
data L=N[Char]|C L 
f 0=N
f n=C. f(n-1)
```

Haskell's strict type system prevents returning different types (Strings vs. List of Strings vs. List of List of Strings,...), so I have to define my own type that accommodates all those cases. The main function `f` recursively calls `n` times the constructor `C` for nesting and `N` for the base case.

Usage example (with `deriving (Show)` added to the new `data` type to be able to print it): `f 4 "codegolf"` -> `C (C (C (C (N "codegolf"))))`.

Edit: @Christian Sievers saved 2 bytes by rewriting the function in a point-free style for the string argument. Thanks!

Comment: Of course Haskell's lists can be nested, but a function cannot return a string for one value and a list of lists of strings for another value of the same type. Golfing the additional `deriving` clause: the parens aren't needed. - Not sure if it's okay to only nest the `C` constructor which isn't list-like. My very similar attempt was based on a data type defined as `data  D x=J x|L[D x]`.

Comment: If you reverse the order of the arguments and don't use an infix operator, you don't need to mention the second argument: `f 0=N;f n=C. f(n-1)`

Comment: @ChristianSievers: yes, you're right, my explanation about nested lists was not accurate - I've changed it. Regarding list-likeness: I think my data structure is list-like. Compare a native Haskell list `1:(2:(3:([])))` with C (C (C (N "codegolf"))). `C` is cons (`:`), `N` is nil (`[]`).

Comment: `C` doesn't cons, it only embeds, your data type can't express `[["a","b"],["c"]]`. But maybe that is fine as this problem only needs singletons.  - `f n=...` isn't point-free. Point-reduced?

Comment: You spend 19 characters defining your data type.  Wouldn't it be more sensible to use an existing type (e.g. `Either`) even if it meant the constructors were a little more verbose?

Comment: @PeriataBreatta: no, that's not possible. You can nest `Either`, but the nesting level would be fixed for function `f`. For example, the type for a nesting level of 2 `Left (Left (Right "golf"))` is `Either (Either (Either a String) b) c)` which is different from level 1 `Left (Right "golf") :: Either (Either a String) b`. With my custom data structure the type of f is L, regardless of the nesting level.

Comment: Hmm.  I was thinking that the type of the function would be `t` where `t = Either String [t]`, but it seems that is explicitly caught and produces a specific error when you try to do it. :(

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 32 bytes

```python
lambda s,n:eval('['*n+`s`+']'*n)
```

Puts `n` open brackets before the string and `n` close brackets before it, then evals the result. If a string output is allowed, the `eval` can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 83 bytes

```
(for((c n))(set! s(apply string-append(if(= c 0)(list"[\'"s"\']")(list"["s"]")))))s
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s n)
  (for ((c n))
    (set! s (apply string-append
                   (if (= c 0)
                       (list "[\'" s "\']")
                       (list "[" s "]"))
                   )))
  s)
```

Testing:

```
(f "test" 3)
```

Output:

```
"[[['test']]]"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 4 bytes

Input is `string` then `n`. Golfing suggestions welcome. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YGtgbg&input=InN0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3ciCjU)

```
`k`n
```

**Ungolfing**

```
          Implicit input string, then n.
`...`n    Run the function n times.
  k         Wrap the stack in a list.
          Implicit return.
```

Answer (score 1):

### [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp) (repl), 34 bytes

```
(d F(q((S N)(i N(F(c S())(s N 1))S
```

Defines a function `F`. Technically, tinylisp doesn't have strings, but this code will work for any data type it's given.

Ungolfed (key to builtins: `d` = define, `q` = quote, `i` = if, `c` = cons, `s` = subtract):

```
(d nest
 (q
  ((item number)
   (i number
    (nest (c item ()) (s number 1))
    item))))
```

Example usage:

```
tl> (d F(q((S N)(i N(F(c S())(s N 1))S
F
tl> (F 2 3)
(((2)))
tl> (F () 1)
(())
tl> (F (q Hello!) 7)
(((((((Hello!)))))))
tl> (F c 3)
(((<builtin function tl_cons>)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 24 bytes

```
#(nth(iterate list %)%2)
```

Clojure is somewhat competitive here. `iterate` creates a sequence of `x, (f x), (f (f x)) ...`, `nth` returns needed element.

See it online: https://ideone.com/2rQ166

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 43 bytes

```
(s:Any,n:Int)=>((1 to n):\s)((_,x)=>Seq(x))
```

Explanation:

```
(s:Any,n:Int)=>   //define a function
  (               
    (1 to n)      //create a range with n elements
    :\s           //foldRight with s as a start value
  )(              //using the following function:
    (_,x)=>Seq(x) //ignore the value of the range and wrap the accumulator in a list
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 bytes

```apl
(⊂⍣⎕)⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b/Go66mR72LH/VN1QRikNj/NC71jEx1LlMA)

(note: the number of leading spaces in the output show how much the string is nested)

#### Explanation

```apl
⎕            take the string as input
  ⍣⎕         take the number (let's call it n) as input and n times
⊂             nest
             the string
```

Comment: Might want to unhighlight your explanation

Comment: Save a byte: [`⊂⍣⎕⊢⎕`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/9fXfyobcKjvql@wQqPetcoPOpuUTCzsgIKBLvqhTr7uqgn5Vco5Ocp6Kbl2ebnqT/qWlysl5qXmJSTGuzoEwJW/6hrUbEeUIdzpHpxYk6Jei3QIK5HHe1p/x91NT3qXQyUAioBkv@Bgv/TuNQzMtW5TAE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
V´?[ß]:U
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VrQ/W99dOlU=&input=ImNvZGVnb2xmIgozCi1R)

Requires the `-Q` flag in order to output the returned array with the brackets and quotes.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 28 bytes

`#(nth(iterate list %)%2)` is the shortest (already posted) solution, so here is something different:

```
#(apply comp(repeat % list))
```

This takes arguments via currying:

```
(def f #(apply comp(repeat % list)))
((f 3) "test")
; ((("test")))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 43 bytes

```
(defun f(x n)(if(= n 0)x(list(f x(1- n)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJTWtNE8hTaNCIU9TIzNNw1YhT8FAs0IDKF2ikaZQoWGoC5QBgf8aBUWZeSUKQFGlxJy0RCUFY6AgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 31 bytes

```
L,$Vd"]"*$"["*B]G$V"'"d@jGbU@jv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HRyUsRSlWSUtFKVpJyynWXSVMSV0pxSHLPSnUIavs////SsUlicnZ@WWpRWk5@eVK/43@5ReUZObnFf/XzQQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) v2, 2 bytes

```
g₎
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wP/1RU9///9HRSsUlicnZ@WWpRWk5@eVKOgaxOhhihljETGNjAQ)

Although I can't think of what subscripting `g` could hypothetically do other than nesting arrays as it does, it can't be ruled out that getting stuck with a 10-byte solution on this challenge might have influenced it, so here's a version that doesn't use `g` at all:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) v2, 3 bytes

```
∈ⁱ⁾
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/1FHx6PGjY8a9/3/Hx2tVFySmJydX5ZalJaTX66kYxCrgyFmiEXMNDYWAA)

The main difference between `g` and `∈` is that `g` constrains its output to be a single-element list containing its input, while `∈` constrains its output to be any list containing its input--it just so happens that in the absence of backtracking or any prior constraints the simplest list containing its input is the one containing nothing else. The difference which adds a byte is that subscripting `g` changes how many layers of array the output gets wrapped in, but it's far more useful in every circumstance except this one for `∈` to constrain the index of the input in the output when subscripted instead, so we need to use `ⁱ` to iterate instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) with extensions, 109 bytes

```hs
data Q a where E::Q();R::Q n->Q[n]
type family n&a where()&a=a;[n]&a=[n&a]
(#)::a->Q n->n&a
a#E=a
a#R n=[a#n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9BC4JAEIXv/opBQ/TQHzAMAi2iQygGgXiY3C2XtlF0IfrzbbNRx7rMY96bD950OF2l1tYKNAgFINw7OUrIk6SI4kXJAjRfFjU1nnkMEs54U/oBFH4uozjEFBecs9ZsN14UxEmCDDmSHQ@DPHWzBEprDKixN1SUgug9gGFUZGAGTIHfcZfeh/yHPyv/RC60z/as8TLZ@bHitmtXVkm3ZvzfTpH4RvtBjmj60e0HErJVAk9abmkySO0b2ayyanoB)

#### Examples

```hs
"Hello"#E = "Hello"
"Hello"#R E = ["Hello"]
"Hello"#R(R E) = [["Hello"]]
```

#### Explanation

This is based loosely on the Agda solution. Since type literal numbers aren't very nice in Haskell, the numerical argument to `(#)` is given in unary format. Rather than taking space to define a `Nat` kind, we use `()` for zero and `[]` for successor. The type signature is mandatory thanks to the GADT argument.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 20 bytes

```
[ [ 1array ] times ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxCoAwDAXQ3VN8egBBRz2AuLiIU@kQSkSx2pIGxdNX8O1vJa9RyjKP09CBROjNOEk3JGHVN8l@KQ6WiwP6qjJZyR/xZllDfAzaYmHR/BEOup@c4YqnEFCXDw)

- `1array` Create an array with one element from an object.
- `times` Call a quotation a certain number of times.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
$(w
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiJCh3IiwiIiwiXCJzdGFja292ZXJmbG93XCIsIDJcblwic3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvd1wiLCA1Il0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 27 bytes

```arturo
$[s,n][do.times:n->s:@[s]s]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?SLvTvw)

Recursion is 2 bytes longer:

```arturo
f:$[s,n][(0=n)?->s->f@[s]n-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 23 bytes

```
f=(s,c)=>c?[f(s,c-1)]:s
```

Try it:

```js
f=(s,c)=>c?[f(s,c-1)]:s

console.log(JSON.stringify(f("stackoverflow",0))); // 'stackoverflow'
console.log(JSON.stringify(f("stackoverflow",1))); // ['stackoverflow']
console.log(JSON.stringify(f("stackoverflow",2))); // [['stackoverflow']]
console.log(JSON.stringify(f("stackoverflow",5))); // [[[[['stackoverflow']]]]]
```

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NYu3TbZ1i7ZPjpdI1nXUDPWqvh/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrqGV7C/n15xSVFmXnpmWqVGmoZScUlicnZ@WWpRWk5@uZKmhoGmpqa1gr6@gjqKjDoXacYYwoyJRjMnlkSDjOAGYZhEqlGmCKOisZgGBP8B). Note, though, that your solution is identical to [Neil's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96513/58974).

Comment: @Shaggy I saw Neil's answer but I think it doesn't meet the requirements because it requires two arguments to be passed, like `(string,number)` rather than `(string)(number)`

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 bytes

```
s{W
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWi4urw5cUJyUXQ_kL1heXJCZn55elFqXl5JdzmUKEAQ)

If we could take input the other way round, the `s` could be dropped.

##### Explanation

```python
s{W  # Implicit input
s    # Swap so the number is on top
 {   # And, this many times, repeat the following:
  W  #  Wrap TOS (initially string input) in a list
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## GNU sed 44 Bytes

Includes +1 for -r

```
s/(.*),(1*)/\2"\1"\2/
:;s/1(.*".*)1/[\1]/;t
```

[Try it online!](http://sed.tryitonline.net/#code=cy8oLiopLCgxKikvXDIiXDEiXDIvCjo7cy8xKC4qIi4qKTEvW1wxXS87dA&input=c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdywxMTE&args=LXI)

Takes the depth to nest the string as a unary number based on [this consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary?answertab=votes#tab-top)
Example:

```
$ echo 'stack"o,verflow,1111' | sed -rf nest.sed
[[[["stack"o,verflow"]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 42 bytes

```py
def f(a,b):
 if b:f([a],b-1)
 else:print a
```

Recursive function

Comment: Did you see the [shorter version of this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96488/53748) that was posted by the OP?

Comment: @Jonathan - yes I did after I had posted. Should I remove mine?

Comment: It's up to you. I'm not downvoting it.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll leave it as an alternative until it gets downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

## Postscript, 24 bytes (11 bytes in binary encoding)

```
{{1 array astore}repeat}
```

Takes arguments on the stack, n at top-of-stack and s under it

The binary encoding is

```
{{1\x92\x09\x92\x0b}\x92\x83}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy, <s>33</s> <s>37</s> 34 Bytes

Groovy's inject method is weird, but essentially is the fold method.

```
{a,n->(0..<n).inject(a){i,r->[i]}}
```

<s>Edited to make it valid for `n=0` using ternary.</s>

Edited again with `..<` to make the integer range an empty set when `n=0` thanks to @manatwork.

Comment: Is the wrapping count correct? I'm afraid it adds and extra layer. Anyway, `{a,n->(0..<n).inject(a){i,r->[i]}}` seems enough: http://pastebin.com/GwpBQd1A

Comment: @manatwork Ahhh... THAT IS AWESOME. I've never seen that notation for integer ranges!

Answer (score 0):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 22 Bytes

```
►xX=x=1\_1:[s]xPX=}x
```

### Explination

```
►xX=x=1\_1:[s]xPX=}x
►                   # Spaceless segment.
 xX=                # Assign 'x' to X
    x=              # Assign the string input to 'x'
      1\_1:       } # Push 1, flip it under the number input Then floor it, converting it from a string(?) to an integer, push another one, execute it as a for loop (i=1; i<=INPUT; i+=1)
           [            # Pop the incrementer of the for loop. We don't need it here.
            s]      # Push a new stack, then clone it.
              xP        # Push x, (Either the current bottom stack or the string), Push it to the new stack
                X=  # Assign it back to 'x' (This is why we set X to x)
                   x    # Push x to the reg stack. Implicitly return.
```

Easy enough, fun to finally get to use multi-dimensional stacks.

[Try it Online!](https://tehflamintaco.github.io/Reverse-Programmer-Notation/RProgN.html?rpn=%E2%96%BAxX%3Dx%3D1%5C_1%3A%5Bs%5DxPX%3D%7Dx&input=13%20%22Hello%2C%20World!%22)

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 47 Bytes

```
function(a,b)for _=1,a do b={b}end return b end
```

A huge amount of this is boiler plate, because of Lua.
`for _=1,a do b={b}end` is the real meat.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lithp](https://github.com/andrakis/node-lithp), 48 Bytes

```
#S,N::((if (== 0 N) (S) ((list (n S (- N 1))))))
```

Can be assigned to a variable or function definition like so:

```
(def n #S,N::((if (== 0 N) (S) ((list (n S (- N 1)))))))
```

And called:

```
(print (inspect (n "stackoverflow" 5)))

[[[[["stackoverflow"]]]]]
```

(inspect is used because JS' print method stops if the object is too deep.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Convex](http://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 4 bytes

```
'a*~
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=J2Eqfg&input=&args=Y29kZWdvbGY+MTA)

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 41 bytes

Actually, it can be done with Haskell's standard list type. Here is how:

```
n?s|m<-([1..n]>>)=read$m"["++show s++m"]"
```

`m` is a local helper function that repeats a string `n` times. It is used in `?` to prepend `n` `[` and append `n` `]` to the result of `show s`, which for a string `s` is that string surrounded by quotation marks and with its possible own quotation marks escaped. This is then parsed by `read` which tries to return the type at which the result is used. The infered type of `?` is `(Enum a2, Num a2, Read a, Show a1) => a2 -> a1 -> a`. It could be specialized by setting `a1` to `String` and `a2` to `Integer` or `Int`, removing all but one of the constraints. But of course it is golfier to let the compiler infer a complicated type than to explicitely state a simple one.

Now simply calling the function in the interpreter gives an ambigous type variable error, but we can state the expected type or use the value in a way that gives enough information to infer the type:

```
Prelude> 2 ? "codegolf" :: [[String]]
[["codegolf"]]
Prelude> putStrLn $ 2 ? "hi" !! 0 !! 0
hi
Prelude> [[["test"]]] ++  (3 ? "hi")
[[["test"]],[["hi"]]]
Prelude> map(map("a":)) $  [2 ? "x" ++ 2 ? "y"] ++ 3 ? "z"
[[["a","x"],["a","y"]],[["a","z"]]]
Prelude> let x=(2 ? "golf") in (x,"code"++x!!0!!0)
([["golf"]],"codegolf")
Prelude> 0 ? "hi" ++ "!"
"hi!"
```

There is no reason to only use strings:

```
Prelude> map(map not) $ 2 ? False
[[True]]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Julia 77 bytes

```
U(n)=Val{n}
g(::U(1),s)=[s]
g{n}(::U(n),s)=[g(U(n-1)(),s)]
f(n,s)=g(U(n)(),s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, <s>60</s> 43 bytes

```
f(a:Any,c:NNI):Any==(c<1=>a;f(copy[a],c-1))
```

Possibly one can use less characters but this is one here compile smoothly without warning... I don't know too if it is right copy one parameter in a recursive function but this silent all warning...

Answer (score 0):

## [Symbolic Python](https://github.com/FTcode/Symbolic-Python), 31 bytes

```
__('_=_[_>_]'+';_=[_]'*_[_==_])
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K67MTcrPyUzWLagsycjP@/8/Pl5DPd42PjreLj5WXVvdOt42GsjQAgrY2sbHav7//1/JIzUnJ19JR8EUAA)**

```
__('_=_[_>_]'                       Var1 = input string
             +'     '*_[_==_])      Nest depth times do:
               ;_=[_]                   Make Var1 a list containing itself
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 34 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,n:n and f([s],~-n)or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRoVgnzypNI7o4VqdON08zM00hTyE1pzhVofj/f/WM1JycfIXy/KKcFHUA)

<s>This might be about as short as I can make it.</s>

Turns out, if you look at super old submissions, you can shave bytes off that you didn't see before. Huh.

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 23 bytes

```
f=s=>n=>n?f([s])(n-1):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@/8/zbbY1i4PiOzTNKKLYzU18nQNNa2K/xcUZeaVaKRpKGWk5uTkK2lqGGtq/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 42 bytes

```
proc N s\ t {time {set s \{$s\}} $t;set s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFPoThGoUShuiQzN1Whuji1RKFYIaZapTimtlZBpcQaLFD7v6C0pFghGqi2JDE5O78stSgtJ79cwTD2PwA)

Comment: Recursive approach did not render shorter: **50 bytes** `proc N s\ t {expr {$t?"\{[N s [expr $t-1]]\}":$s}}` https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WcFPoThGoUShOrWioEihWqXEXimmOhooqBANFlEp0TWMjY2pVbJSKa6t/V9QWgKUAUqXJCZn55elFqXl5JcrGMf@BwA